# windows mobile error log

Tags: windows-mobile

Developing a windows mobile 5 .net cf 2 application. Using the error log generator documented here:

[Error Logging Link](http://blogs.msdn.com/davidklinems/archive/2006/08/17/704662.aspx)

My simple question is WHERE are the error log files actually stored on the mobile device? Google doesn't seem to be much help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

> By default, log files are written to
>   the directory that contains the
>   application that is being diagnosed.

From : [How to: Create Log Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229650.aspx). Does this help?